# mySQL search for id in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, wordpress

I want to filter my SQL query with some array of IDs.

so I have IDs for example: 2,3,4 and `activity_meta.value` 1,2,5;
And I want to find every activity where it has id in `activity_meta.value`

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, u.user_email, u.user_nicename, u.user_login, u.display_name
FROM wp_bp_activity a
LEFT JOIN wp_users u
ON a.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN wp_bp_activity_meta
ON (a.id = wp_bp_activity_meta.activity_id)
WHERE a.is_spam = 0
AND a.hide_sitewide = 0
AND a.type != 'activity_comment'
AND  (wp_bp_activity_meta.meta_key = 'activity_tagz' )
DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I want to add `AND (1,2,3 IN wp_bp_activity_meta.meta_value)`
I just dont know how to treat serialized array;

Comment: so u have the ids as array ?

Comment: actually this is string separated by commas

Comment: ah thats easy then just use `wp_bp_activity_meta.meta_value IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Will `IN` work? thats better since wordpress `Meta_Query` supports that (when `FIND_IN_SET` is not). Is there any performance difference

Comment: No it wont,you are comparing csv string with int.

Comment: anybody willing to submit an answer? :)

Comment: @Mpa4Hu first attempts will come soonish - Good answers require some thinking :)

Comment: @Mpa4Hu "1,2,3" is a String value of the field value? Is it always orderd by size, does it contain gaps? would `2,1,3` or `1,15,2` also be possible values?

Comment: No gaps, I check before inserting. and also not ordered but I can do this before inserting, I'm just building it so wherever is better.

This is a just a string of tags IDs that this activity is associcated with and another set is users favorite tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `activity_meta.value` is not normalized. It would be a better choice, to create a second table, where you assign the meta tags to your element.

So, it would look like:

```
wp_bp_activity_id | meta
1              | 1
1              | 2
1              | 3
```

let's cal this table "meta_relation". Then you simple could either use a subselect, like this:

```
... WHERE wp_bp_activity.id in (SELECT wp_bp_activity_id FROM meta_relation WHERE meta in (1,2,5))
```

Or you could implement this with another join, like

```
... INNER JOIN meta_relation ON wp_bp_activitiy.id = meta_relation.wp_bp_activity_id
```

(will return 3 rows then for 3 matching tags)

```
... WHERE meta in (1,2,5)
... GROUP BY wp_bp_activity.id
```

(will remove any duplicate result and unwanted tags)

---

For your current scenario you could use a workaround. However this requires to build up the query programmatically:

For each "Tag", you want to find (i.e. `1,2,5`) you need to add another or-condition.

- To make sure you are not matching the `2` within `125` you can sourround it by `,`.
- To make sure, you are not missing the FIRST or LAST item (which has no leading / trailing `,` you need to concatenate the column with 2 more `,` in the first place:

Query then contains the following additional criterias.

```
SELECT
   ....
WHERE 
   ... 
AND
(
   CONCAT(CONCAT(",", activity_meta.value ), ",") LIKE "%,1,%" OR
   CONCAT(CONCAT(",", activity_meta.value ), ",") LIKE "%,2,%" OR
   CONCAT(CONCAT(",", activity_meta.value ), ",") LIKE "%,5,%"
)
```

if you want all 3 tags to appear, use `AND` instead of `OR`.

in your example, this will match :

```
,2,3,4, against ,1, 
,2,3,4, against ,2, //match
,2,3,4, against ,5,
```

Order and / or gaps don't matter with this approach.

(Depending on whether its a 10 User Website or a Million-Customer-Portal, you can use either. Preferred Solution is to normalize your table.)

Comment: So you are suggesting to save multiple metas instead of using one like array? just to be sure I understand everything

Comment: @Mpa4Hu See my update: Yes this is called database normalization: A `field value` should have ONE value. If you want multiple values, use multiple rows.

Comment: Normalizing database just for readability or performance? If performance I all into it, but there can be millions of activity and each activity can have from one to 10 tags, so I'm thinking how this is productive

Comment: @Mpa4Hu for performance and for better Handling. (Readability is actually worse, cause you need to lookup multiple tables)

Comment: Thanks, I go with this then.

Comment: @Mpa4Hu its never bad to do things right :-) Queries are untested, and only suggestions on what you should look for. if you want to dig in, google for `n:n` or `many to many` relations. (`1:n` or `one to many` looks the same, but has just a different (composite) key constraint))